# Unable to compare two to_date columns in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the code

```
and replace(to_char(to_date(FDP.Period_NAME,'MM-YY'),'MM-YY'),'-','') 
        <= replace(to_char(to_date('JAN-16','MM-YY'),'MM-YY'),'-','')
```

And the error

> Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
>   01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: What is `FDP.Period_NAME`? Sounds like it's not a valid format

Comment: You have a wrong format mask in `to_date('JAN-16','MM-YY')`.See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924). Besides, what do you need to do?

Comment: So you are converting a string to date and then to string and then comparing strings with '<=' ?

Comment: I assume you should better do `AND TRUNC(FDP.Period_NAME, 'MM') <= DATE '2016-01-01'`

Comment: @Aleksej - `to_date('JAN-16','MM-YY')` 'works' and gives you 2016-01-01, but only because Oracle is helpful and tries alternative masks (unless you specify FX). But agree the appropriate mask should be used anyway - MON, or since that's affected by NLS keep MM but give the month number; or even better use an ANSI date literal for the fixed value...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting....

The Oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm) says that the format mask 'MM' matches "Month (01-12; January = 01)" but you use 'JAN' that should'nt work.

But when I tested your code on my database it mysteriously works !!!

```
SQL> select replace(to_char(to_date('JAN-16','MM-YY'),'MM-YY'),'-','') from dual;

REPLA
-----
0116
```

Still I would change the 'JAN' to '01' and verify that the column FDP.Period_NAME DOES NOT contain abreviation of months like 'JAN','FEB'...

OR change your format mask to match abbreviated month names (i.e. 'MON').

Comment: The flexibility is well known behaviour, even if the docs don't make it clear. You can change the behaviour with [the FX format modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF30004): "Format exact. This modifier specifies exact matching for the character argument and datetime format model of a TO_DATE function".